# Is there a way to send user-specific push notifications for iOS devices?

Tags: ios, objective-c, node.js, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I would like to know if I can create a service to send customized user-specific push notifications for iOS.

#### Example

> @"Hey %@, how you doin", firstName"

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I completely misunderstood what you need, no answer has what you need.

Here's a relevant example from the [APNS guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1) :

let’s consider an example. The provider specifies the following dictionary as the value of the alert property:

```
{ "aps" : 
  {
    "alert" : {
        "loc-key" : "GAME_PLAY_REQUEST_FORMAT",
        "loc-args" : [ "Jenna", "Frank"]
    }
  }
}
```

> When the device receives the notification, it uses "GAME_PLAY_REQUEST_FORMAT" as a key to look up the associated string value in the Localizable.strings file in the .lproj directory for the current language. Assuming the current localization has an Localizable.strings entry such as this:
>
> "GAME_PLAY_REQUEST_FORMAT" = "%@ and %@ have invited you to play Monopoly";
>
> the device displays an alert with the message “Jenna and Frank have invited you to play Monopoly”.

Answer (score 0):

Of course. Check out the APNS programming guide, specifically the payload, which you can customize on your server before you send it to the user's device.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

Also note that if you know when the notification should appear (not at a dynamic time) then look into local notifications, which don't require a server backend.

Comment: i don't know when to appear and i already got my server up and running where i can send simple push notifications with HELLO WORLD.

Comment: @user3819540 at the point where you setup the HELLO WORLD string, make that dynamic based on the user's information in your database. That way it will be specific to the recipient. Post your code if you'd like and we can have a look.

Comment: thats the issue how can i make it dynamic?I m just using a simple example push with body payload HELLO WORLD

Comment: @user3819540 Whenever your server triggers to send out a new push, you will need to know who is the recipient. I'm assuming you will have both the push device identifier and the recipient's name linked in your database, so at that point you can dynamically set the payload message that is sent to Apple's servers.

Comment: dude :) yes exactly i have those informations and you are saying what i want to do but you are not saying how can i get there :)

Answer (score 0):

There are some very good solutions for iOS push notifications service that use APNS. No need to implement it on your own.

- [PushApps](http://www.pushapps.mobi) - free for 1M notifications per month, and unlimited notifications for 19.99 per month, and you can import your users via the API or by sending the a csv file - [documentation](http://wiki.pushapps.mobi/display/PUSHAPPS/PushApps+Home)
- [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/) - free up to 1M notifications per month, afterwards you are charged per 1000 notifications
- [Parse](https://parse.com/) - also free for the first 1M notifications
- [PushWoosh](http://www.pushwoosh.com/) - free for 1M devices, premium plans are from 39 EURO

If you have to implement it on your own, have a look at [easyAPNS](http://www.easyapns.com/) if you want to host it yourself.

Another good site for info is Ray Wenderlich's site which hosts a 2 part tutorial:

- [Apple Push Notification Services Tutorial: Part 1/2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12)
- [Apple Push Notification Services Tutorial: Part 2/2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3525/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-2)

Or [this](https://github.com/argon/node-apn), Apple Push Notification module for Node.js.

Comment: none of them provide what i want to.They just sent segmented push notifications

Comment: No, you are wrong. You can upload/link your database with users and send user-specific notifications. We use Parse in my company for that it.

Comment: well thanks for your help but we can not use any third party for this job.

But what you do is exactly what i want to do, link database input with tokens and send notifications based on the users personalized push.

Comment: Ok, got it. Then, you will have to implement your own APNS service on your server. I updated my answer with some useful links.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any service for Push Notification (as listed) or do it by yourself.

In your code, when you receive the Push Notification message:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    NSLog(@"Received notification: %@", userInfo);
    //here you should treat your received data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can...

You need to create your own back-end php file for push notification service, you can send json data from your app to the php file and use `$GET` to achieve the data you want, including device token, message, badge number... please refer to [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

in your viewController

```
NSString *finalUrl =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/pushService.php?device_token=%@&passphrase=%@&msg=%@",baseURL,device_token,passphrase,msg];
NSURL *url  =[NSURL URLWithString:finalUrl];
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

if(jsonData != nil)
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
    NSLog(@"result: %@", result);

}else
{
    NSLog(@"connection error!");
}
```

pushService.php file

```
// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = $GET['device_token'];

// Put your private key's passphrase here
$passphrase = $GET['passphrase'];

// Put your alert message here:
$message = $GET['msg'];

$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default',
    'badge' =>  5 
);
```